# jquery form submit in callback function doesn't work on IE

Tags: jquery, forms, callback

I have the following code which, within jquery callback function, append a form and submit it.  It works w/o problem in chrome, but doesn't work in IE. Any reason and workaround for it?

```
var email = $('#account_email_form #email').val();
$.post('/controllers/forget_password.php',
  { email: email },
  function(message) {
    var form = $('<form id="submit_email_form" action="/email_sent" method="POST">' + 
      '<input type="hidden" name="email" value="' + email + '">' +
      '</form>');
    $('#submit_email_form').appendTo('body').submit();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$('#submit_email_form')` because the form is not in the DOM yet.

```
form.appendTo('body').submit();
```